# TopicSubscriber - not receiving old messages

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have a queue with hundreds of messages enqueued, and less than 10 dequeued.

```
<topic name="TEST.FOO.TOPIC ">
<stats size="0" consumerCount="5" enqueueCount="183" dequeueCount="18"/>
</topic>
```

I am trying to obtain all the hundreds of messages (which are several months old), but neither `MessageListener` nor `receive()` give me any of the old messages. It only gives me any newly enqueued messages from today.

How can I obtain the old messages (that were never dequeued) from a topic?

### More info

- I tried adding `consumer.retroactive=true` to the topic name, but that had no effect.
- My `activemq.xml` is the same as that provided in the default distribution.

Comment: This can be configured, but the default is only 64kb according to the book "ActiveMQ in Action" (though not stated here http://activemq.apache.org/subscription-recovery-policy.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only receive messages published when the consumer was offline if you created a durable subscriber.

Comment: So the subscriber has to be known to the active mq system at the time of message enqueing to have access to that message?

Comment: Yes, for a non-durable Topic subscriber it needs to be active when the message is sent or the message is effectively sent to /dev/null

Comment: Actually I think you are answering a slightly different question. What I'm asking is, suppose I have a durable subscriber. Will it be able to read messages that were enqueued before the subscriber was created?

Comment: No. Most JMS systems discard messages once they have been delivered to all applicable connected consumers and durable subscribers. You might need something like Kafka based on your questions.